# How to get 2 ends of (elongated) polygon in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, polygon, distance

I have an elongated polygon with irregular shape.

[image]

I need to find its ends. I assume it's elongated and in this case it's easy to spot it visually, but mathematically is a bit tricky.

I've tried to approximate this problem to finding 2 most distance points while keeping their "deltas" on perimeter constant. This is the code:

```
> print(x)
             x1       x2
  [1,] 609899.7 217820.0
  [2,] 609909.9 217817.8
  [3,] 609912.2 217812.9
  [4,] 609916.9 217811.8
  [5,] 609924.0 217809.7
  [6,] 609927.2 217809.9
  [7,] 609930.2 217812.0
  [8,] 609934.9 217808.8
  [9,] 609938.0 217808.7
 [10,] 609941.2 217809.2
 [11,] 609945.8 217805.9
 [12,] 609954.2 217806.9
 [13,] 609953.0 217800.7
 [14,] 609957.3 217799.9
 [15,] 609962.0 217798.8
 [16,] 609967.0 217798.8
 [17,] 609971.3 217800.0
 [18,] 609977.4 217802.9
 [19,] 609986.0 217807.4
 [20,] 609987.0 217803.8
 [21,] 609990.4 217804.1
 [22,] 609996.3 217808.9
 [23,] 609999.4 217809.0
 [24,] 609999.4 217804.0
 [25,] 609994.1 217802.3
 [26,] 609990.0 217801.2
 [27,] 609985.4 217798.0
 [28,] 609982.0 217798.2
 [29,] 609979.0 217798.2
 [30,] 609973.4 217797.0
 [31,] 609970.1 217795.6
 [32,] 609961.8 217796.4
 [33,] 609957.4 217797.1
 [34,] 609953.0 217798.3
 [35,] 609948.9 217799.3
 [36,] 609945.3 217801.0
 [37,] 609939.2 217806.0
 [38,] 609936.0 217806.2
 [39,] 609932.3 217806.1
 [40,] 609928.0 217807.3
 [41,] 609924.9 217807.2
 [42,] 609921.3 217807.1
 [43,] 609917.0 217808.3
 [44,] 609912.9 217809.2
 [45,] 609908.3 217810.1
 [46,] 609898.3 217817.0
 [47,] 609892.1 217824.8
 [48,] 609893.1 217828.8
 [49,] 609896.2 217829.1
 [50,] 609898.1 217834.8
 [51,] 609899.3 217839.0
 [52,] 609899.1 217842.1
 [53,] 609902.2 217848.9
 [54,] 609905.3 217855.0
 [55,] 609909.1 217862.2
 [56,] 609917.2 217873.9
 [57,] 609921.3 217879.9
 [58,] 609935.1 217894.1
 [59,] 609939.3 217902.0
 [60,] 609943.4 217909.1
 [61,] 609946.1 217915.2
 [62,] 609949.3 217922.1
 [63,] 609953.4 217929.1
 [64,] 609957.0 217936.2
 [65,] 609961.6 217944.4
 [66,] 609967.4 217953.1
 [67,] 609971.0 217960.2
 [68,] 609976.5 217969.2
 [69,] 609981.4 217977.1
 [70,] 609984.9 217984.2
 [71,] 609989.9 217992.6
 [72,] 609994.4 218000.1
 [73,] 609997.0 218006.3
 [74,] 610000.9 218005.6
 [75,] 610000.5 218001.9
 [76,] 609998.6 217996.1
 [77,] 609991.8 217988.1
 [78,] 609990.2 217981.5
 [79,] 609984.5 217975.8
 [80,] 609981.0 217968.6
 [81,] 609978.6 217960.1
 [82,] 609974.6 217958.8
 [83,] 609971.0 217951.6
 [84,] 609965.8 217943.1
 [85,] 609967.5 217934.9
 [86,] 609957.7 217929.9
 [87,] 609955.8 217924.7
 [88,] 609954.5 217919.2
 [89,] 609954.4 217916.0
 [90,] 609945.7 217905.9
 [91,] 609944.0 217901.4
 [92,] 609945.6 217894.1
 [93,] 609938.9 217890.1
 [94,] 609935.6 217882.1
 [95,] 609923.0 217874.8
 [96,] 609923.4 217869.0
 [97,] 609916.1 217865.4
 [98,] 609911.9 217858.3
 [99,] 609912.6 217850.1
[100,] 609905.1 217845.4
[101,] 609903.8 217840.9
[102,] 609902.9 217836.2
[103,] 609900.7 217831.0
[104,] 609901.2 217825.1
```

The functions to get something:

```
## Get all deltas between points (on line)
deltas = NULL; dsum = 0
for (i in 1:nrow(x)) {
  if (i == 1) {
    d = sqrt((x[i,1]-x[nrow(x),1])^2 + (x[i,2]-x[nrow(x),2])^2)
  } else {
    d = sqrt((x[i,1]-x[i-1,1])^2 + (x[i,2]-x[i-1,2])^2)
  }
  ddf = data.frame(id = i, x = x[i,1], y = x[i,2], delta = d, d_agr = dsum, stringsAsFactors = F, row.names = NULL)
  deltas = rbind.data.frame(deltas, ddf)
  dsum = dsum + d
}

# provisional opposite vertex index
povi = which(deltas$d_agr > dsum/2)[1]

maxd = 0; nac = 0; p1 = 0; p2 = 0
for (i in 1:povi) {  #i=28
  idx = i
  iv2 = which(deltas$d_agr > dsum/2+deltas$d_agr[idx])[1]
  if (is.na(iv2)) {
    nac = nac + 1
    idx = nac
    iv2 = which(deltas$d_agr > dsum/2+deltas$d_agr[idx])[1]
  }
  d = sqrt((x[idx,1]-x[iv2,1])^2 + (x[idx,2]-x[iv2,2])^2)
  if (d > maxd) { maxd = d; p1 = i; p2 = iv2 }
}
```

Now if I print `print(c(maxd, p1, p2))` I get that my points are 20 and 73, so they are close but they are not those ends.

```
plot(x, pch=20, cex=0.1)
text(x, cex=0.5, pos = 1, offset = 0.1)
```

[image]

I'd rather bet for 24 & 74. So my effort is not what I wanted. What's more important, I don't need to keep "deltas" between those points constant because finally, having 24 and 74 I'd like to know their distance "up" and "down" the ring.

Any hints from you how to take this approach. I'd need to have O(n) like this one.